# Соединение зашифровано с помощью устаревших наборов шифров

Tags: nginx, ssl

Народ, помогите плиз понять почему ошибка. Купил сертификат на godaddy, и он работает, но выбивает предупреждение "Соединение зашифровано с помощью устаревших наборов шифров" вот картинка

[image: Соединение зашифровано с помощью устаревших наборов шифров]

Как это можно поправить? В качестве веб сервера использую ngix.

Конфиг

```
server {
        listen 443;

        server_name example.com;
        root /home/wordpress/www; # путь к WP
        index index.php;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.com_combined.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key; 
}
```

nginx -V

```
nginx version: nginx/1.9.3 (Ubuntu)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module
```

grep -rn ssl_ /etc/nginx

```
 /etc/nginx/snippets/snakeoil.conf:4:ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    /etc/nginx/snippets/snakeoil.conf:5:ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:33:       ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:34:       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    Binary file /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com matches
```

Comment: добавь в вопрос конфиг nginx

Comment: Добавил конфиг.

Comment: ясн. тогда `nginx -V` показывай

Comment: добавил nginx -V

Comment: нужные настройки по умолчанию, версия больше 1.9.1, так что странно. вангую либо наличие настроек там где ты их не ищешь (прошу `grep -rn ssl_ /etc/nginx`), либо нужно обновить nginx и openssl, либо проблема в другом ПО. преглагаю сделать греп, обновиться, рестартоваться и посмотреть. если нет изменений то настроить ссл_протоколс и ссл_шиферс как тут в самом начале http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html и смотреть дальше

Comment: Добавил grep -rn ssl_ /etc/nginx

Comment: Заметил что на других сайтах не используют HMAC-SHA1. Может дело в этом. Как мне его отключить?

Comment: Закомментируй 33-34 в nginx.conf и рестарт

Comment: Класс. Супер. В этом и была проблема! Большое спасибо :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32558/discussion-between-dimaua-and-norbornen).

Comment: Через часок, я в дороге

Answer (score 1):

Ответ по результатам обсуждения: закомментировать в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` строки 33-34.

Кроме того, в документации nginx вместо `ssl  on;` рекомендуют использовать `listen 443 ssl;`

Хотел ещё сказать, что [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) вышел из инвайт-режима, так что космические корабли бороздят просторы, а получение сертификатов перестало быть синонимом покупки.